# How to fix the trait `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `parity_scale_codec::Compact<sp_runtime::Perbill>`?

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, pallet-staking

When building my parachain, I run into the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `parity_scale_codec::Compact<sp_runtime::Perbill>: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/frame/staking/src/lib.rs:412:18
    |
412 |     pub commission: Perbill,
    |                     ^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `parity_scale_codec::Compact<sp_runtime::Perbill>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen`:
              parity_scale_codec::Compact<u8>
              parity_scale_codec::Compact<u16>
              parity_scale_codec::Compact<u32>
              parity_scale_codec::Compact<u64>
              parity_scale_codec::Compact<u128>

error[E0277]: the trait bound `parity_scale_codec::Compact<Balance>: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/frame/staking/src/lib.rs:424:9
    |
424 |     value: Balance,
    |            ^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `parity_scale_codec::Compact<Balance>`
    |
help: consider extending the `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
420 | #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, parity_scale_codec::Compact<Balance>: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen)]
    |                                                                                     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `parity_scale_codec::Compact<<T as pallet::pallet::Config>::CurrencyBalance>: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/frame/staking/src/lib.rs:448:13
    |
448 |     pub total: BalanceOf<T>,
    |                ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `parity_scale_codec::Compact<<T as pallet::pallet::Config>::CurrencyBalance>`
    |
help: consider extending the `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
439 |     MaxEncodedLen, parity_scale_codec::Compact<<T as pallet::pallet::Config>::CurrencyBalance>: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen,
    |                  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `parity_scale_codec::Compact<<T as pallet::pallet::Config>::CurrencyBalance>: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/frame/staking/src/lib.rs:452:14
    |
452 |     pub active: BalanceOf<T>,
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `parity_scale_codec::Compact<<T as pallet::pallet::Config>::CurrencyBalance>`
    |
help: consider extending the `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
439 |     MaxEncodedLen, parity_scale_codec::Compact<<T as pallet::pallet::Config>::CurrencyBalance>: parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen,
    |                  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `pallet-staking` (lib) due to 4 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav-parachain %
```

How do I resolve this issue?
This is [github](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/xcav-parachain/tree/fixing-staking-pallet-issue) code repo.

Comment: What version of `parity-scale-codec` are you using? There was a recent bug, `3.6.5` should work.

Comment: `3.0.0` I am using

Answer (score 1):

There has be a bug in the recently released SCALE version `3.6.6` and it has been yanked since.
Please fix the version to one earlier like this: `=3.6.5`. Just using `3.0.0` could have pulled in the faulty version.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround**: Patching the dependency in the root `Cargo.toml` should solve the issue for now:

```
[patch.crates-io]
parity-scale-codec = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec.git", tag = "v3.6.5" }
```

Comment: should I comment `from runtime` and `node`?

Comment: No, you should put it in the base `Cargo.toml` file, where you define the workspace members.